# How do I enable archiving in HBase/Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, opentsdb

We need to enable archiving for Hadoop/Hbase. How do I enable archiving in HBase/Hadoop?

Sorry, I tried google but couldn't find the exact command/parameters.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Are you talking about snapshots? http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops.snapshots.html